# Need assistance with deserializing an odd Json structure

Tags: java, jackson

I'm working with a web service that enjoys making wheels.  For a sequence of objects, instead of storing the data inside a JSON array, they make a new node for each index of the sequence.

```
{
    "sequence": {
        "0": {
            "foo": "foo",
            "bar": "bar",
            "baz": "baz"
        },
        "1": {
            "foo": "foo",
            "bar": "bar",
            "baz": "baz"
        },
        "2": {
            "foo": "foo",
            "bar": "bar",
            "baz": "baz"
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if anyone had an elegant solution or sane approach to deserialize this into an array or collection of Sequence beans with jackson

```
public class SequenceElement {
    String foo, bar, baz;
    // Getters and setters below
}
```

Working with the sequence as a JsonNode is the best thing I can come up with atm, here is some untested sudo code.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();    

@JsonProperty("sequence")
public void setSequence(JsonNode sequence) {
    List<SequenceElement> list = new ArrayList<SequenceElement>();

    int i = 0;
    while( sequence.get( String.valueOf(i) ) != null ) {
        JsonNode element = sequence.get( String.valueOf(i) );
        list.add( objectMapper.readValue( element, SequenceElement.class );
        i += 1;
    }

    this.sequence = list;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the twist on reinventing the wheel :) As for solution, I think your best bet is to read it into a generic json object and convert it into the sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by generic json? are you talking about just storing it as an string and dealing with it later down the road?

Comment: No, I think reference is to a tree, like `JsonNode root = mapper.readAsTree(source);`, then accessing parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend on @SubirKumarSao's already correct answer, here is a way to get your sequence items as a list, in the same order as guaranteed by the data indices:

**Data classes**:

```
public class Sequence {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    private String baz;

    // Constructors, getters/setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Sequence[foo=%s, bar=%s, baz=%s]", getFoo(),
                getBar(), getBaz());
    }
}

class SequenceHolder {
    private Map<Integer, Sequence> sequence;

    public SequenceHolder() {
        sequence = new TreeMap<Integer, Sequence>();
    }

    // Other constructors, getters/setters
}
```

**Main logic**:

```
final String json = "JSON HERE";

final SequenceHolder holder = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json,
        SequenceHolder.class);
System.out.println(holder.getSequence().values());
```

Tested with this modified version of your JSON (to illustrate ordering):

```
{
    "sequence": {
        "0": {
            "foo": "foo0",
            "bar": "bar0",
            "baz": "baz0"
        },
        "1": {
            "foo": "foo1",
            "bar": "bar1",
            "baz": "baz1"
        },
        "2": {
            "foo": "foo2",
            "bar": "bar2",
            "baz": "baz2"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

> [Sequence[foo=foo0, bar=bar0, baz=baz0], Sequence[foo=foo1, bar=bar1, baz=baz1], Sequence[foo=foo2, bar=bar2, baz=baz2]]

As you can see, you get a list of items, in the same order as that guaranteed by your data indexes (the key being the use of a tree map).

Answer (score 3):

IMO `Map<String,Sequence>` Should be Java equivalent for the JSON Object.

Comment: Yes. And even `Map<Integer,Sequence>` may work via implicit coercion.